# Find the number of matrices $A$ with distinct elements such that $AA^{-1}=I$where $I$ is unit matrix of order $2$.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be a square matrix of order $2$ where $a_{ij}\in\left\{0,1,2,3,4,6\right\}$.Find the number of matrices $A$ with distinct elements such that $AA^{-1}=I$,where $I$ is unit matrix of order $2$.

---

My Attempt:
Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix}$
So,$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}
    d & -b \\
    -c & a
  \end{bmatrix}$
$AA^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    d & -b \\
    -c & a
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{ad-bc}{ad-bc} & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{ad-bc}{ad-bc}
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$
We have to find the number of ways in which $a,b,c,d$ can be arranged such that no number is repeated.So i counted $6\times 5\times 4\times 3=360$,but the book says the answer is $344$.
I dont know where i have gone wrong and what is the correct way to solve it.Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for $A^{-1}$ to exist, $ad-bc \neq 0$.  So how many ways can you choose $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: I got it,thank you.@Morgan Rodgers

Answer (score 1):

The number of matrices with different terms among the given set is $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot 3$. Now count the singular matrices among those ones and substract. Note that the two rows of a singular $2\times2$ matrix are proportional.