Number of $2\times 2$ invertible matrices with entries in $\{0,1,2,3,4,6\}$?

If $A$ is a square matrix of order $2$ whose elements are taken from the set $\displaystyle \left\{0,1,2,3,4,6\right\}$.Then the number of matrices $A$ such that $A^{-1}$ exists,is

What I try: Here $\displaystyle A^{-1}$ exists ,if $|A|\neq 0$
First we will calculate total number of matrices for which $|A|=0$ or $|A|\neq 0$
So let we  have $\displaystyle A = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$
Where $\displaystyle a,b,c,d\in \left\{0,1,2,3,4,6\right\}$
So total no. of matrices $\displaystyle = 6\cdot 6\cdot 6\cdot 6=6^4$
Now matrices $A$ for which $|A|\neq 0$
$\displaystyle \bullet $ any one row elements or any one column are zero, Then total ways $\displaystyle (6^2)\cdot 4=144$
$\displaystyle \bullet$ If $3$ zeros, Then total matrices $6(4)=24$
$\displaystyle \bullet $ If all elements are zero, Then only one matrices
$\displaystyle \bullet $ If $A = \pmatrix{1&2\\3&6}$, Then $8$ such matrices .
$\displaystyle \bullet$ If $\displaystyle A = \pmatrix{2&4\\3&6},$ Then $8$ such matrices
So total matrices for which $|A|=0$ is $\displaystyle =144+24+1+8+8=185$
So no. of matrices for which $A^{-1}$ exists $\displaystyle 1296-185=1111$
Please tell me is my process is right and also please tell me is any  shorter method exists , thanks

Have a read of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496438/find-the-number-of-matrices-a-with-distinct-elements-such-that-aa-1-iwher
Do the entries need to be distinct?

Do you work modulo 7?

@FinnT , Here entries are not distinct.

No @MartinBrandenburg, Can you please explain me. Thanks

Instead of finding specific ways the determinant could be zero, we know that the determinant is zero if and only if $ac = bd$. So, if for every integer $k$ we count the $n_k$ number of ways to pick $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ such that $ac=bd=k$ then we can add sum these to get our answer. Note that the number of ways to choose $a$ and $c$ such that $ac = k$ is the same number of ways to pick $b$ and $d$ such that $bd=k$.
For the case when $k=0$ we need either $a$ or $c$ to be $0$. If there is one 0 then we have to choose which of $a$ or $c$ will be $0$ and we are left with 5 remaining possibilities. If $a=c=0$ there is only one way to pick this. Hence, there are $n_0 = 2*5+1=11$ ways to pick $a$ and $c$ such that $ac=0$ .
For the case when $k=1$ we need $a=c=1$ so there is only one possibility ($n_1=1$).
You can continue this for $k=2,3,4,6,8,9,12,16,18,24,36$ (its easier than it looks).

 I got the following values for the rest of the $n_k$ values: $n_2 = 2$, $n_3 = 2$, $n_4 = 3$, $n_6 = 4$, $n_8 = 2$, $n_9=1$, $n_{12} = 4$, $n_{16} = 1$, $n_{18} = 2$, $n_{24} = 2$, and $n_{36}=1$

We then have that $n = \sum_{k} (n_k)^2$ is the total number of our matrices whose determinant is 0, which we can then subtract from $6^4$ to get our answer. As a check, we have that $\sum_k n_k = 36$. (Why?)

 I got the answer to be 1110.

